# Disjoint refinements in $P(\kappa)/J$

Tags: set-theory, reference-request

The following is a theorem of Baumgartner, Hajnal, and Mate:

Suppose $J$ is a normal ideal on $\omega_1$ which is nowhere $\omega_1$-dense.  Then for any sequence $\langle A_\alpha : \alpha < \omega_1 \rangle$ of $J$-positive sets, there is a sequence $\langle B_\alpha : \alpha < \omega_1 \rangle$ of pairwise disjoint positive sets such that $B_\alpha \subseteq A_\alpha$ for all $\alpha$.

The proof is specific to $\omega_1$.  But I conjecture that ZFC+CH proves the same statement with $\omega_1$ replaced by $\omega_2$ throughout.

Is the conjecture true?  Are there any related results you think might shed light on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my [thesis](http://www.math.uci.edu/~meskew/thesis.pdf) I proved that my conjecture is false.  It's not so simple-- the proof ties together chapter 2 and sections 5.1, 5.2, and 6.3.